# How to define my own (recursive) Coq notations?

Tags: recursion, operators, coq

I've started working a lot with `Ensemble`s now, because they are more flexible. To help me with that, I'm trying to define some convenient notations. The following is relatively easy, for example:

```
Notation "a ∈ S" := (@In _ S a)  (at level 80).
```

And I can add a similar bunch for the other binary set operators.

But I'm having a lot of trouble with notations like this:

```
Notation "∀ x ∈ S , P" := (forall x, (x ∈ S) -> P)  (at level 90).
```

It is accepted, but whenever I try to use it I get this error:

> Syntax error: "∈" expected after [constr:operconstr level 200] (in [constr:operconstr]).

**Question 1:** What am I doing wrong?

For bonus points, can you tell me how to define a recursive notation for it? I've tried, but it seems to give me a whole new set of problems. Here's my attempt, a straightforward edit of the library definition:

```
Notation "∀ x .. y ∈ S , P" :=
  (forall x, (x ∈ S) -> .. (forall y, (y ∈ S) -> P) ..)
  (at level 200, x binder, y binder, right associativity).
```

I don't see why the library version in `Coq.Unicode.Utf8_core` should parse and mine shouldn't, but:

> Error: Cannot find where the recursive pattern starts.

**Question 2:** See question 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the  recursive notation above didn't work is that binders (in this case `x` and `y`) can *only* be used in one of two specific locations in the right hand side [[see manual](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#sec524)]:

- at the binder location in a `fun [ ] => ...` term, or
- at the binder location in a `forall [ ], ...` term.

So, I could not use them again as terms. This seems somewhat arbitrary to me, since binders *are* terms within their binding context. However, you can do pretty much anything you want with the `fun` route:

```
Definition all_in_E `(E: Ensemble T, P: T → Prop) : T → Prop :=
  (λ x: T, (x ∈ E) → (P x)).

Notation "∀ x .. y ∈ S , P" :=
  ( all ( all_in_E S ( fun x => .. ( all ( all_in_E S ( fun y => P ))) .. )))
  (at level 200, x closed binder, y closed binder, right associativity).

Definition ex_in_E `(E: Ensemble T, P: T → Prop) : T → Prop :=
  (λ x: T, (x ∈ E) ∧ (P x)).

Notation "∃ x .. y ∈ S , P" :=
  ( ex ( ex_in_E S ( fun x => .. ( ex ( ex_in_E S ( fun y => P ))) .. )))
  (at level 200, x closed binder, y closed binder, right associativity).
```

The functions `all_in_E` and `ex_in_E` take a predicate (a `fun`) and augment it with a condition for membership in a given ensemble `E`. It's taking the long way around, but it works.

Here's a fully working block of code with examples:

```
Require Export Coq.Unicode.Utf8.
Require Export Coq.Sets.Ensembles.

Generalizable All Variables.

Notation "a ∈ S" := (@In _ S a)            (at level 70, no   associativity).
Notation "A ∪ B" := (@Union _ A B)         (at level 50, left associativity).
Notation "A ∩ B" := (@Intersection _ A B)  (at level 40, left associativity).

Definition all_in_E `(E: Ensemble T, P: T → Prop) : T → Prop :=
  (λ x: T, (x ∈ E) → (P x)).

Notation "∀ x .. y ∈ S , P" :=
  ( all ( all_in_E S ( fun x => .. ( all ( all_in_E S ( fun y => P ))) .. )))
  (at level 200, x closed binder, y closed binder, right associativity).

Definition ex_in_E `(E: Ensemble T, P: T → Prop) : T → Prop :=
  (λ x: T, (x ∈ E) ∧ (P x)).

Notation "∃ x .. y ∈ S , P" :=
  ( ex ( ex_in_E S ( fun x => .. ( ex ( ex_in_E S ( fun y => P ))) .. )))
  (at level 200, x closed binder, y closed binder, right associativity).

Section TestingEnsembleQuantifiers.
  Definition A_nat := Full_set nat.
  Definition E_nat := Empty_set nat.
  Definition F_nat := Singleton _ 5.

  Require Import Coq.Arith.Gt.

  Example exists_in_intersection: ∃ x ∈ A_nat ∩ F_nat , x = 5.
    unfold ex_in_E.
    exists 5.
    split ; trivial.
    split.
    apply Full_intro.
    apply In_singleton.
  Qed.

  Example forall_in_union: ∀ x ∈ F_nat ∪ E_nat, x ≥ 5.
    unfold all_in_E, all.
    intros.
    destruct H ; destruct H.
    auto with arith.
  Qed.
End TestingEnsembleQuantifiers.
```

Please note also the new precedence levels for the set operators, which make more sense in relation to the existing precedence levels [[see manual](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual005.html#init-notations)].